# Passing an object reference to a vuejs component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I need to pass an object reference to a `vue`-component. The background behind this is the following:

I have a webapp, that uses `vuejs` only for the chat. However, the webapp already opens a `WebSocket`-connection to my server for data messaging. I would like to reuse this existing `WebSocket`-connection inside the `vue`-powered Chat, instead of opening another parallel connection. I was struggling for some time to pass the `WebSocket` object from my webapp to the `vue`-component.

I want to pass a reference to a fully dynamic `WebSocket`-connection, so `props` or `state` are no option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite easy to pass a reference to an arbitrary object to a `vue`-component. Suppose you mount your app as follows:

```js
this.app = new Vue({
    render: (h) => h(Chat),
}).$mount("#myChatApp");
```

Setting the reference on the `app`, i.e. `this.app = myWebSocket` won't expose the `WebSocket` to the Chat component, but only to the global `Vue`-instance. Instead you have to access the component through:

```js
this.app.$children[someIndex].ws = myWebSocket;
```

And voíla: It works! I'm just getting started with `vuejs` and amazed how it all boils down to pure `js`. Hope this helps somebody who stumbles over a similar problem!

Comment: Yea that's one of the great things about vue - transparent javascript.